# What does the error fabs(sc) > DBL_EPSILON mean in function cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv-solvepnp

I am using the solvePnPRansac function from OpenCV (4.0.0) in python. Sometimes (but not all the time) when I pass points into the function I get an error:

```
(-215:Assertion failed) fabs(sc) > DBL_EPSILON
```

in function `cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2' called from 'solvePnPRansac' (the function I am directly using). Does anyone know what this means or what might be going wrong?

In my use case, I am using 'solvePnPRansac' like this:

```
_, rvec, t, _ = cv2.solvePnPRansac(pts_3D, pts_2D, K, distortion_coefficients)
```

Comment: Can you give a (simple) specific example that triggers this error for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case `pts_3d` contained some NaN values. After excluding the specific rows in `pts_3d` and `pts_2d` the error was gone.